# The estimate time when meting or replacing song in a YouTube studio

Tags: youtube, youtube-live, youtube-studio

Does someone know the estimated time for doing mute / replace song on YouTube?
Let's say my YouTube video (a live past stream to be precise) contain song with 5 minutes song. Then I do song mute / replace, technically it's different, so I assume it will differ the mute and replacement. Is it possible that the processing takes less time than 5 minutes, I mean less than the duration of the sound to be added? The new studio takes some time before the copyright claim appears, I assume they (the machine) already have metadata (cache or some sort).

Answer (score 0):

It's should take less than a day. That is the rough estimation.
It also depends on the youtube server, since many don't know.
The user upload rate on youtube is high, I assume that that slow down or consuming their resources.

Further info, that it takes a day or two even to process your live stream, so you can use the blur effect via youtube studio. The site might take priority among the creator, perhaps the creator who is in the youtube partner program will have faster results.